# Angularjs directive attributes properties all undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive with the following definition

```
LastMeet.directive("progressBar", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      meeting: "&meeting"
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

      var meeting = scope.meeting();

      // Gather the details we need about this meeting
      var startDate = scope.meeting().start_datetime;
      var deadline  = scope.meeting().deadline;
      var complete  = scope.meeting().percentage_complete;
      console.log(meeting);
      console.log(meeting["start_datetime"]);

      // No point doing anything if we're already at 100%      
      if (complete < 100.0) {
        // Calculate how much to increment by every second
        var diff      = deadline - startDate;
        var increment = diff / 60.0;

        var timer;

        scope.percentage = complete;

        scope.onTimeout = function() {

          if (scope.percentage < 100.0) { 
            scope.percentage += increment;
            elm.css({ right: 100 - percentage + "%" });
            timer = $timeout(scope.onTimeout, 1000);
          }

        }

        // Setup our timer and get going :)
        timer = $timeout(scope.onTimeout, 1000);
      }

    }
  }
})
```

The meeting attribute is an object with a number of different properties. As you can see, I've added 2 console outputs, one for the meeting itself, and one for one of the properties I'm trying to access. My console has the following output

```
b {$resolved: false, $then: function, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
   $resolved: true
   $then: function (callback, errback) {
   agenda_items: Array[2]
   deadline: 1365897600
   description: "Meeting to discuss the progress of LastMeet"
   faye_token: "7468585e529849ca992efbd3b9de6337"
   icon: null
   id: 20
   name: "LastMeet"
   percentage_complete: 100
   start_datetime: 1365897600
   __proto__: b
```

This is the output of the meeting object, which clearly shows the `start_datetime` property contained. The second console output however is simply

```
undefined
```

Why is it that the meeting object is there, and I can see everything, but when I try and access the contained properties, I just get undefined every time?

Comment: Meeting is an object and you're treating it like a function in your directive?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Never used angular, but I guess it's the same as Ember. You can bind functions to 'objects.'

Comment: yeah, with angular you've got 3 binding types - text, one-way and two-way. One way bindings (like this one) get turned into methods so you can't then edit it

Comment: I tried but I can't reproduce your problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/bJkSD/) (tested in Chrome).  Can you post a non-working fiddle or plunker?

Comment: I can try but I'm not really sure where the error is coming from, whether it's data being passed in, or within the directive or what. It's pretty confusing :( I'll see if I can get a fiddle put together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUCCESS! So it appears to be an issue with the variable not being fully ready when the directive runs. The meeting object that it was looking at is created via a `resource` which creates a placeholder object whilst it gets the server data, and then populates the object.

My guess, is angular saw that the object existed (actually the placeholder) but the values I wanted weren't actually there yet. Not sure why the console output showed them as being there but oh well. To fix it, I added a `watch` statement to the object which is removed when it actually changes and gets populated. My directive now looks like this

```
LastMeet.directive("progressBar", function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      meeting: "=meeting"
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

      unwatch = scope.$watch('meeting', function(meeting) {
        if (meeting) {
          // Gather the details we need about this meeting
          var startDate = meeting.start_datetime;
          var deadline  = meeting.deadline;
          var complete  = meeting.percentage_complete;

          // No point doing anything if we're already at 100%      
          if (complete < 100.0) {
            // Calculate how much to increment by every second
            var diff      = deadline - startDate;
            var increment = diff / 60.0;

            var timer;

            scope.percentage = complete;

            scope.onTimeout = function() {

              if (scope.percentage < 100.0) { 
                scope.percentage += increment;
                elm.css({ right: 100 - scope.percentage + "%" });
                timer = $timeout(scope.onTimeout, 1000);
              }

            }

            // Setup our timer and get going :)
            timer = $timeout(scope.onTimeout, 1000);
          }

          unwatch();
        } 
      }, true)
    }
  }
})
```

Now I have a few calculation issues but it's working :)